# Creating code logic that uses a for loop to cycle through several arrays

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to create a code logic by using a `for` loop instead of multiple `if` statements.

This is the previous `if` statement code I used before:

```
if (isset($_POST['answer1']))
{
    if ($_POST['answer1'] === '1d')
    {
        print $correct[0];
    }
    elseif ($_POST['answer1'] === '1b')
    {
        print $incorrect[0];
    }
    elseif ($_POST['answer1'] ==='1c')
    {
        print $incorrect[0];
    }
    elseif ($_POST['answer1'] === '1a')
    {
        print $incorrect[0];
    }
};
```

This code allows me to check for the answer and print either the `$correct` or `$incorrect` variable. My issue in this code is that it is very inefficient because I end up having to create ten or so `if` statements.

I came up with a mock-up of the `for` loop code to illustrate:

```
$_SESSION["totalCorrect"] = 0;

if (!isset($_SESSION["totalCorrect"]))
{
    $_SESSION["totalCorrect"] = 0;
}
else 
{
    $totalCorrect = $_SESSION["totalCorrect"];
}

$postAns = array($_POST['answer1'] as $ans1, $_POST['answer2'] as $ans2, $_POST['answer3'] as $ans3, $_POST['answer4'] as $ans4, $_POST['answer5'] as $ans5, $_POST['answer6'] as $ans6, 
$_POST['answer7'] as $ans7, $_POST['answer8'] as $ans8, $_POST['answer9'] as $ans9, $_POST['answer10'] as $ans10);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($postAns); i++)
{
    if ($i == $postAns[])
    {
        if ($postAns[] === 'answer')
        {
            print $correct[];
            $_SESSION["totalCorrect"]++;
        }
        else ()
        {
            print $incorrect[];
        }
    }
};
```

For this code, I have three arrays involved that I am trying to cycle through, `$postAns`, `$correct`, and `$incorrect`. The `$correct` and `$incorrect` arrays, when called, print out text depending on whether they got the answer right.

So for the `for` loop, I want to be able to cycle through each value of the `$postAns` array to check and and see which answer number it is and whether it is the correct answer or not. If it's correct, then the code cycles through `$correct` to get the right text for that answer number and increments the value of `totalCorrect`, the variable that stores how many the user got right. If incorrect, the code cycles through `$incorrect` to get the right text for that answer number.

I'm not really proficient with loops in general so any insight/help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Included the form submission code

```
<form action="staff_info.php" method="get" id="q1">
<fieldset>
<legend>Question 1</legend>
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="1a" id="1a"><label for="1a">  A.  </label>
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="1b" id="1b"><label for="1b">  B.  </label>
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="1c" id="1c"><label for="1c">  C.  </label>
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="1d" id="1d"><label for="1d">  D.  </label>
<input type="button" id="answer" class="button " title="abutton" value="ANSWER">
<a href="staff_q2.php" class="button " title="nbutton" style="float:right;" id="next">NEXT</a>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one thing you're missing in your pseudo code is the actual answers. If you create an array of correct answers as @fefe indicated then the loop will be something like this:

```
$correctAnswers = array(
    'answer1'=>'1d', 
    'answer2' => '2b', 
    'answer3' => '3c', 
    'answer4' => '4b', 
    'answer5' => '5a'
);

$numberCorrect = 0;
$responseIndex = 0;

foreach ($correctAnswers as $key=>$answer) {
    if ($_POST[$key] === $answer) {
        $numberCorrect++;
        print $correct[$responseIndex];
    }
    else {
        print $incorrect[$responseIndex];
    }

    $responseIndex++;
}
```

Comment: Hi, apologies for the late reply, but this code worked with a couple of tweaks. I moved the $responseIndex outside the if statement since it outputted all the text instead of just the correct one, but the general idea of the code was incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you trying to achieve but the loop should look something like this and you can make some validation with `if` or `switch case`.

```
$postAns = array(
    'answer1'=>'ans1', 
    'answer2' => 'ans2', 
    'answer3' => 'ans3', 
    'answer4' => 'ans4', 
    'answer5' => 'ans5', 
    'answer6' => 'ans6', 
    'answer7' => 'ans7', 
    'answer8' => 'ans8', 
    'answer9' => 'ans9', 
    'answer10' => 'ans9'
);


foreach ($postAns as $key=>$ans) {
    var_dump($ans);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry if it seems unclear to you. To clarify, the previous code shown above has about nine other if statements that allowed me to select a radio button, check its value(whether it's the right answer or not), then print either $correct or $incorrect. What I'm trying to achieve by using the for loop is get rid of the if statements and just right a few lines of code that does what the previous code did and also increment the value of $totalCorrect, something the previous code did not do. I hope this helps clarify things.